# Regular expression at switch case

Tags: go, telegram-bot

I need to write a simple telegram bot.
Everything is working except 1 thing. When I'm writing command \task#1 - it should give me the link for it, \task#2 - should give the link to task2, etc.
How to arrange this better or how to make switch case for regular expression?

````
import (
    "log"
    "strconv"
//     "regexp"
    "github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api"
)

func main() {
    bot, err := tgbotapi.NewBotAPI("")
    tasks := [...]string{"Ansible assignment", "Bash script"}
    links := [...]string{"https://github.com/task1", "https://github.com/task2"}
//  var currentTask = regexp.MustCompile(`^task#.`)

    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    bot.Debug = true

    log.Printf("Authorized on account %s", bot.Self.UserName)

    u := tgbotapi.NewUpdate(0)
    u.Timeout = 60

    updates, err := bot.GetUpdatesChan(u)

    for update := range updates {
        if update.Message == nil { // ignore any non-Message Updates
            continue
        }
        log.Printf("[%s] %s", update.Message.From.UserName, update.Message.Text)


if update.Message.IsCommand() {
            msg := tgbotapi.NewMessage(update.Message.Chat.ID, "")
            switch update.Message.Command() {
            case "help":
                msg.Text = "type /sayhi or /status."
            case "homerep":
                msg.Text = "https://github.com/ :)"
            case "tasks":
                msg.ParseMode = "html"
                msg.Text = "The list of completed tasks:\n"
                for i := 0; i < len(tasks); i++ {
                    msg.Text =  msg.Text + strconv.Itoa(i+1) + ". " + tasks[i] +  "  -  " + "<a href='"+links[i] +"'> <b>link</b></a>" + "\n"
                }
            case update.Message.Command == "^task#.":
                msg.ParseMode = "html"
                msg.Text = "This is test"
            default:
                msg.Text = "I don't know that command"
            }
            bot.Send(msg)
        }
}
}```
````

Answer (score 4):

Compile the regular expression and assign it to a package-level variable:

```
var commandPat = regexp.MustCompile(`^task#.`)
```

Modify the switch to use expressions.  Use [MatchString](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.MatchString) for the regular expression:

```
switch cmd := update.Message.Command(); { // note the ; on this line!
case cmd == "help":
   ...
case cmd == "homerep":
   ...
case cmd == "tasks":
   ...
case commandPat.MatchString(cmd):
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @cerise-limón. I did like U proposed, but now have the following error:
`cannot use cmd (type string) as type []byte in argument to commandPat.Match.`
 I have tried to make the following:
` case commandPat.Match([]byte(cmd)): `
But I'm getting such error: 
` panic: Not Found goroutine 1 [running]: log.Panic(0xc000173c40, 0x1, 0x1) /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/log/log.go:338 +0xac main.main() /home/oleg/Desktop/DevOps/Task3/main.go:17 +0x1ae exit status 2 `
Please help

Comment: Oops, I fixed the typo in the answer.  Use MatchString.

Comment: I am not familiar with the API that you are using, but I am guessing that tgbotapi.NewBotAPI("") returns an error because the token is "".